# how to auto update date for three days in dropdown using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have simple dropdown option for three days to select one date but i want that the date will auto update for last three days and it must be in dropdown.

here is my code...

```
<select class="col-md-7" name="dateinfo">
    <option value="02-11-2018">02-11-2018</option>
    <option value="03-11-2018">03-11-2018</option>
    <option value="04-11-2018">04-11-2018</option>
</select>
```

Here is my another code in which i have used datepicker ....

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -3, maxDate: "0" });
  } );
  </script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I want this in dropdown...

Comment: Where's the php?

Comment: #HTMLIsNotCode #sad

Comment: no php, i have done it using jquery but it is not in dropdown,

Comment: i just want to show last three days in dropdown

Comment: You have a list of dates that want to wrap last three date in select tag?

Comment: where is the jQuery code?

Comment: You must use jQuery to calculate dynamic date. Please try to write code in javascript/jQuery and let us share your code with issue if you will face.

Comment: i have added another one....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have tried a manual way of adding dates for next 3days when you select a date from input box.
You can get new dates by adding the number of days in the `date` object

Example:

```
var d1 = new Date(newDate);
d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 2);
```

it gets the date of day after tomorrow.

So, you want to get the next 3 day dates in the select box. So, make a loop for 3 times and append the date to the `option` field.

```js
$("#getdate").on('change', function() {
  $('#dates').find('option').remove().end();
  var newDate=this.value;
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    var d1 = new Date(newDate);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + i);
    $("#dates").append('<option>'+d1.getDate()+'-'+(d1.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d1.getFullYear()+'</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <input type="date" id="getdate"></input>
  <select id="dates">
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Edit

```js
//$("#getdate").on('change', function() {
  //$('#dates').find('option').remove().end();
  //var newDate=this.value;
  var newDate = new Date();
  console.log(newDate.getDate());
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    var d1 = new Date(newDate);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() - i);
    $("#dates").append('<option>'+d1.getDate()+'-'+(d1.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d1.getFullYear()+'</option>');
  }
//});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  
  <select id="dates">
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to show only second selection box, which contains today and last two dates

Comment: @Bhawesh okay, just remove the date text field and get today date using `new Date()`

Comment: @Bhawesh is that what you are asking?

Comment: i want current and past two days

Comment: just remove `+` and add `-`

Answer (score 0):

How about below,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - i);
    var optionValue = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', d)
    //OR var optionValue = d.getDate() +'-'+ (d.getMonth()+1) +'-'+ d.getFullYear();
    $("#dateinfo").append("<option value=" + optionValue + ">" + optionValue + "</option>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select class="col-md-7" id="dateinfo">
</select>
```

$.datepicker.formatDate is a functionality of jQuery UI. If you don't want to use jQuery UI, just remove the commented code and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below code It will work.

```
<?php
$date=date('Y-m-d');

$Dates[0]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date)));
$Dates[1]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($date)));
$Dates[2]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 day', strtotime($date)));

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var js_DateArray = new Array();

    <?php
    $i=0;
    if (!empty($Dates))
    {
        foreach ($Dates as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo "js_DateArray[$i]=new Array('".$value."');\n" ;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    ?>

var html = [];

for (i = 0; i < js_DateArray.length; i++)
{   html.push("<option>" + js_DateArray[i] + "</option>")   }
     $("#dropdown").html(html);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="dropdown">

</select> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

let's try someting like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<select class="col-md-7" name="dateinfo">
    <option value="02-11-2018">02-11-2018</option>
    <option value="03-11-2018">03-11-2018</option>
    <option value="04-11-2018">04-11-2018</option>
</select>

<script>

    var dates = {
        selected : '',
        dateArr : []
    }



    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
        ).on("change", function (e) {
            dates.selected = new Date(e.target.value);

            var optDate = new Date();

            optDate.setDate(dates.selected.getDate() - 1);

            dates.dateArr.length = 0;
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                var optDate = new Date();
                optDate.setDate(dates.selected.getDate() - i);
                dates.dateArr.push(optDate)
            }

            var str;

            dates.dateArr.forEach(function (date) {
                str += "<option value='"+ date.toISOString().split('T')[0]+ "'>"+ date.toISOString().split('T')[0]+ "</option>";
            })
                $(".col-md-7").html("").append(str);

            // console.log(dates)
        })


    } );
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```